# Is keeping a mutable reference to my Logger a good idea?

Tags: c++

I have an abstract `Logger` class with a virtual `Log(std::string const&)` method. That way I can implement any type of logging.

The method is not const because I could, for example, create a Qt implementation of my Logger (`QtLogger`). It would log to a widget, therefore modifying an object.

Now let's say that I keep a unique `QtLogger` object and pass it by reference to any object that needs to log something. The problem is that the `Log()` method is not const, so I can't log anything in a const method...

Is it a good idea to keep a mutable reference to my `QtLogger`?

If yes, then why do I get the following error with gcc? (4.6.1)
`reference ‘_logger’ cannot be declared ‘mutable’ [-fpermissive]`

**Edit:** How I declared the reference: `QtLogger mutable& _logger;`

Comment: Kinda of lost in the story (and I have never used mutable), but can a const cast resolve your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A logger interface should always be `const`, the user doesn't have to know that you *may* change stuff when he logs something. A better design would be to make the `Log` method `const` and tell the derived classes that they have to make their members `mutable` if they want to change them in the log method - don't push that part on the user!

To answer your actual question, I assume you defined the reference like so:

```
QtLogger& mutable _logger;
```

If yes, this won't work, since a reference itself can't be changed anyways. You need to move the `mutable` like so:

```
QtLogger mutable& _logger;
```

If you defined the `_logger` in another way, please show your code.

Comment: My code exactly:  
`Logger mutable& _logger;`. I don't understand the error gcc is giving me. Anyway, thanks! I'll do what you said :)

Comment: @paps: Strange stuff, but please try my suggestion in the first part of the answer, maybe the problem resolves itself alread with that. :P